# How to generate current date of the day ,to store it in postgreSQL databse

Tags: java, postgresql, date

I needed to store current date in postgresql database.So,in which format I use the date so that it matches the date format of postgresql and how to get it in java.

```
date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
String SQL = "insert into aqitable values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL,state,city,location,date,pm10,pm2dot5,no2,o3,co,so2,nh3,pb,AQI);
```

Comment: show us some code. what are you using JPA or JDBC

Comment: Like java, Postgres Date does not have any intrinsic formatting when being inserted, it is inserted as a date not a String

Comment: `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: If you're asking about how to do this from Java, the answer is that you would use JDBC with a Postgres driver, and much of what you are asking would be taken care of under the hood automatically.

Comment: Dates should be stored as date, not as string in a specific format

Comment: What did your search and research bring up? You’re not asking us to write your code for you, are you?

Comment: Your search might have brought this up: according to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), you may use `CURRENT_DATE` in your `insert` statement to have today’s date inserted. It doesn’t seem to let you control time zone, though, which may be a reason for preferring to find the date in Java as in [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774281/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    1 ,
    LocalDate.now(
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    )
)
```

## Details

No strings attached. So no "format" needed.

To store a date-time value in a database you define a column with a date-time data type and pass a date-time Java object through your [JDBC driver](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver).

Getting a current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, pass the modern java.time types directly. Call [`java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

If not compliant, fall back briefly to the troublesome legacy java.sql types. Convert to/from java.time via new methods added to the old classes. In this case, [`java.sql.Date.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-).

```
myPreparedStatement.setDate( … , java.sql.Date.valueOf( ld ) ) ;
```